# Energy distribution of incoming muons from cosmic rays

Tags: cosmic-rays

I believe there has been research done which provides data on the kinetic energies of muons which result from incoming cosmic rays. I'm looking for a graph of counts (vertical axis) vs. kinetic energy (horizontal axis.)

Comment: Have you read [the chapter on the subject in the PDB (PDF link; 2018 edition)](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-cosmic-rays.pdf) yet? Is the data therein somehow insufficient?

Comment: I haven’t. Thank you for the link.